# How to create a .NET Background Service that only listens for events?

Tags: c#, events, service, background

I need to do some fairly granular analysis of Windows events on some servers, and forward them to a syslog server.  I've created a .NET Service which is working quite well, but there are some aspects to this that I do not understand.

Here's the Program.cs, which is pretty much out-of-the-box, but I've added some configuration stuff to it:

```
using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .UseWindowsService(options =>
  {
    options.ServiceName = "LEULogSenderSVC";
  })
  .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
  {
    IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
    LEULogConfig options = configuration.GetSection("LEULogConfig").Get<LEULogConfig>();
    services.AddSingleton(options);
    services.AddHostedService<LogMonitorSvc>();
  })
  .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

Here is the LogMonitorSvc.cs (edited for brevity):

```
  public sealed class LogMonitorSvc : BackgroundService
  {
    private readonly ILogger<LogMonitorSvc> _logger;
    private static LEULogConfig _options;
    private static MessageFiltering systemLogRules { get; set; }
    private static MessageFiltering applicationLogRules { get; set; }

    private static void OnApplicationEntryWritten(object source, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
    {
      //Process Application Log Entry, optionally send to syslog...
    }

    private static void OnSystemEntryWritten(object source, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
    {
      //Process System Log Entry, optionally send to syslog...
    }

    public LogMonitorSvc(ILogger<LogMonitorSvc> logger, LEULogConfig options)
    {
      _logger = logger;
      _options = options;

      EventLog systemLog = new EventLog("System", ".");
      EventLog applicationLog = new EventLog("Application", ".");

      systemLogRules = MessageFiltering.DeSerialize(options.SystemLogRulesFilePath);
      systemLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(OnSystemEntryWritten);
      systemLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

      applicationLogRules = MessageFiltering.DeSerialize(options.ApplicationLogRulesFilePath);
      applicationLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(OnApplicationEntryWritten);
      applicationLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
      while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
        //_logger.LogWarning("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

        await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
      }
    }
  }
```

Every example I've found seems to assume that there's something going on periodically (almost always a timer-based event) that causes the 'Task' to run.  I don't need that, I simply register two Event Handlers, and the service should just chill (which it does) until one of those events occurs, at which time the appropriate On...EntryWritten handler runs.  Again, this is basically working, but it feels quite kludgy.

So, my questions are as follows:

1. Do I need the "await host.RunAsync()" line at the end of program.cs?  I can't figure out how to get rid of it, because the service just dies if it's not there.
2. My ExecuteAsync code simply drops in for a visit every 10 seconds and does nothing.  Is there something else I can put in there that essentially says "Wait indefinitely without pinning my CPU"?
3. What's the correct way to setup error handling in this situation?  If something goes haywire during initialization (e.g. file not found), I'd like to prevent the service from starting, but if I throw an error in the constructor, it seems to proceed as if nothing happened.
4. Is there a better way to approach this?  I wonder what happens if a burst of events happen all at once - will the various events be handled in their own thread, or do they get queued up, etc.?

Thanks in advance for any advice...

Comment: We do run something like this in a production environment for over a year without any issues so far. I would suggest using `await Task.Delay(-1, stoppingToken);` this will block indefinitely until the `stoppingToken` gets cancelled. And surrounding it with a `try{} catch(TaskCanceledException){break;}`. But it definitely feels hacky. Maybe there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need the "await host.RunAsync()" line at the end of program.cs? I can't figure out how to get rid of it, because the service just dies if it's not there.

Yes. The host is what creates and starts the background services. You still need to run the host.

> My ExecuteAsync code simply drops in for a visit every 10 seconds and does nothing. Is there something else I can put in there that essentially says "Wait indefinitely without pinning my CPU"?

You can feel free to ignore `ExecuteAsync` if that works for you:

```
protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
```

This is one way of thinking of event-based background services: the constructor starts it and `Dispose` stops it, and `ExecuteAsync` is ignored.

An alternative perspective is to have a minimal constructor (generally considered good design), and have `ExecuteAsync` be its "main loop". I.e., it starts when `ExecuteAsync` starts, and it cleans up before exiting `ExecuteAsync`. In this case, the "infinite" delay is a normal way to do nothing until shutdown is requested (via the `CancellationToken`).

> What's the correct way to setup error handling in this situation? If something goes haywire during initialization (e.g. file not found), I'd like to prevent the service from starting, but if I throw an error in the constructor, it seems to proceed as if nothing happened.

Are you sure? Throwing an exception from a constructor should prevent the host from even getting its list of hosted services.

> Is there a better way to approach this? I wonder what happens if a burst of events happen all at once - will the various events be handled in their own thread, or do they get queued up, etc.?

That is entirely dependent on the implementation of `EventLog`. I'm fairly sure that each event will come in on a thread pool thread.

Comment: Thanks for the great information!  The only thing I'm still a little murky over is how to make my constructor more 'minimal' - how would I rewrite what I've got to make the ExecuteAsync the "main loop", whilst reading files/creating Event Handlers once and only once?

Comment: @user3311566: You'd keep the lines setting `_logger` and `_options`, and move the rest of the code to the beginning of `ExecuteAsync`.